# How to merge csv using string match and aggregate function efficiently in python pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes which I want to merge on two columns state and district, here my two df's :

[This is my first df, which is the result of pd.merge of two df:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hQak.jpg)

[dataframe 2 where first DF's state , district columns to be matched](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNdPm.jpg)

this is one to many relation ship right now but I need to pick only those result which has a maximum total population value viz. "total_P_total", here is my try out code which will work but I do not think it is efficient to go in loop for every district, this below code is giving me single record for "dhubri" district

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame()

df = Tot_Pop[Tot_Pop.Name.str.contains('dhubri',case=False)]   
final_df = df[df.TOT_P_Total == df.TOT_P_Total.max()]

final_df.head()
```

Please help me with the short and efficient code.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create DF on both of these dictionaries

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda','Toyota','Ford','Audi'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

cars_models = {'Model Name': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }
```

Merge the DF on a cloumn name

```
print (pd.merge(car_df, model_df, on='Price'))
```